# Why is this small MLP in TF nearly 7x faster than PyTorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

my small model in Tensorflow:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(20, input_shape=(61,), activation='tanh'),
    Dense(10, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(1, activation=None, dtype='float32')
])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics="Accuracy")
from time import time
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=2048, verbose=2)
```

this takes around ~10s to complete this (~50ms per epoch)

but this pytorch model, is taking around 70 seconds to complete:

```
# the model
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(61, 20),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(20, 10),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(10, 1),
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc(x)


class CLF(object):
    def __init__(self, train_loader):
      self.train_loader = train_loader

    def fit(self):

        model = MLP()
        model = model.to("cuda")        
        loss_func = nn.BCELoss()
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

        for _ in range(200):
            for inputs, targets in self.train_loader:
                inputs, targets = inputs.to("cuda"), targets.to("cuda")
                targets = targets.reshape(-1,1)
                model.zero_grad()
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                outputs = model(inputs)
                clf_loss = loss_func(outputs, targets)
                clf_loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
        self.model = model

# the loader code

train_tensor = TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(x_train), torch.Tensor(y_train))
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_tensor, batch_size=2048, shuffle=False)
clf = CLF(train_loader)
clf.fit()
```

The steps to get x_train and y_train, were the same. Why is there this big difference in running time. Can I make the pytorch model faster?

I tried changing, num_workers, prefetch_factor and used torch.compile. but none helped. I know TF uses static graphs, but do they contribute to this much speedup?

Comment: The main difference would be tensorflow using static graph and pytorch using dynamic graph.<br>
There are a lot of optimization being done, but since tensorflow has static graph, it is optimizing well for the task your model has been designed for, while pytorch is more designed to get on all possibilities.<br>
I don't think that there is a problem with your code. The difference is mainly due to the difference on how the optimization are done inside the frameworks. <br>

Comment: @Toyo Thanks, thats what i thought. is there any new functionality in pytorch to make generate static graphs?

Comment: the only way i can think of is to go through converting your pytorch model to onnx. But, pytorch directly using static graph is not something i have heard about.